# Camshaft Sensor Position problem or Oil Related problem

Tags: oil, vw, jetta, camshaft

I have a 2014 VW Jetta SE. Recently my engine began making an off and on Growling noise while driving around. At the same time, my engine light came on. Took the car to get checked and the reading came back stating that the Camshaft Position Sensor needed replacing.  Part will take about 7 - 10 days to get in so I've been driving around as sparingly as possible. Today (the day the part is to come in) while doing an errand, my oil light flashed red. Took the car to a parts store and purchased 2 bottles of oil. Emptied one bottle into the oil tank, turned the car on and while the car made an initial growl, that noise did not happen again on my drive back to work. Any thoughts or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is this question asking? Are you looking for suggestions for what to do next? Or is this asking whether your car needs its camshaft sensor replaced or just an oil change?

Comment: So what does you oil gauge say? Generally you should check the oil level regularly and refill if necessary. Try to keep it near max. Don´t overfill! Usually the amount needed from min. to max is about 0.5 Liters.

Answer (score 0):

I Don’t think it is a sensor problem simce it is just gathering information and sends it to the ECU. I would rather say it is oil related problem since it is lubricating the engine compenents to provide smooth frictions.